# How to add element conditionally to XSD based on the value of another element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a scenario, where the first element (Mode) can have a value of either Add/Edit/Delete.

Now, I need to have another element (ID) based on the value of the first element.

if the first element value is Add then the XML validation should fail if the second element exists.

if the first element value is either Edit/Delete then the second element is required in the XML for the validation to pass.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="mode">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Add"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Edit"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Delete"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="Request">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Mode" type="mode" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="not(Mode != 'Add') or ID"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I tried adding xs:assert to add conditional validation but I'm getting the below error

> The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:assert' element is not supported in this context.

Comment: The **assert** was introduced in XSD 1.1 in 2012. Unfortunately, .Net Framework doesn't support XSD 1.1

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Understood, thank you. Is there any other way I can achieve what I'm going for without using assert?

Comment: There is no way to accomplish it in pure .Net Framework. Saxon has the best XSD 1.1 implementation. But it is a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

`xs:assert` is only available in XSD 1.1, which .NET does not support.  For XSD 1.1, use [Saxon](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/schema-processing/schema11/) instead.

### XSD 1.0 solution

Content model constraints in XSD 1.0 are based on component names.  You'll have to redesign your XML to represent `Add` vs `Edit` vs `Delete` as elements rather than as attribute values to express `ID`'s different occurrence constraints depending on request type.

Rather than

```
<Request>
  <Mode>Add</Mode>
</Request>

<Request>
  <Mode>Edit</Mode>
  <ID>1</ID>
</Request>

<Request>
  <Mode>Del</Mode>
  <ID>2</ID>
</Request>
```

use

```
<Add></Add>

<Edit>
  <ID>1</ID>
</Edit>

<Del>
  <ID>2</ID>
</Del>
```

This design can easily be accommodated in XSD 1.0.